# How to curl data using Python(NLP/ML etc) built in api in php..?

Tags: python, php

I want to curl **top news**(title, discription, and image) from **any news website** by using **built in** (python/nlp/machine learning)api. And i want to use that api in **php** to get all this data. My problem is i have to fetch data from any news site, so to fetch data from **multiple sites** which **api** i use...

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

To fetch data from multiple API's with cURL you can add multiple cURL requests. Your question is to ambiguous to answer. Please provide an example of your code as different websites will have different API's and requirements. To get a better answer you need to be more specific.